# I need to write a nested if statement with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with a relatively simple macro. I need to check if a value in column i is greater than the value in column N, and if so then check if its lower than the value in column O, the print out the corresponding number of column P in column k. I wrote a macro I thought would work, but when it runs, nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
Sub CountP()
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Set ws = Sheets("Bulk Add")

For Each cell In ws.Range("I2:I2377")
For i = 2 To 49
If cell.Value > ws.Range("N" & i) Then
    For j = 2 To 49
    If cell.Value < ws.Range("O" & i) Then
      ws.Range("J" & j) = ws.Range("P" & i)
    End If
      Next j
    End If
      Next i
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of the values and columns;]

Comment: Why these nested loops? Dont you want to compare values that are on the same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood the problem description the code does not need to loop n*n times. It suffices to find the one pair in the lookup table `(N1:O49)` which contains the value under investigation:

```
Sub CountP()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x

    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    With ws
        For Each cell In .Range("I2:I2377")
            x = cell.Value
            For i = 2 To 49
                If x > .Range("N" & i) And x <= .Range("O" & i) Then
                    .Range("J" & cell.Row) = .Range("P" & i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Result: the number of the range into which the value falls is printed right beside the value, in column J.
Watch carefully how the interval is tested: value needs to be greater than the lower bound and up to the upper bound. This is inconsistent in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks @user1016274 this code works very well! Appreciate your help. The previous attempts weren't throwing up an error when run, but they were also not making any changes on the actual results, so I wasn't sure what was going on.

Comment: If you find the code useful and appreciate it's running linear with `n` in time instead of quadratic, please mark my post as "answer".

Answer (score 2):

Remember to use the Value property when setting cell values. I'm assuming you meant column J as the target column in which to paste the value in column P (it's what's in your code).
This should work and compare, for each row *x*, the value of the cell in column I*x* to all pairs of values in columns N and O. If the value of I*x* is between at least one pair of values in columns N and O it copies the value of J*x* into P*x*

```
Sub CountP()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer    

Set ws = Sheets("Bulk Add")
For i=2 To 2377
  For j=2 To 2377

  If ws.Range("I" & i) > ws.Range("N" & j).Value _ 
  And ws.Range("I" & i).Value < ws.Range("O" & j).Value Then
      ws.Range("J" & i).Value = ws.Range("P" & i).Value

      ' Once you've found one pair of N and O that satisfies the condition, 
      'you move on to the next row, by forcing the j loop to end.

      Exit For 
  End If
  Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @alfymbohm, I think you are on to something, but when I run the macro nothing happens. I think its because if I2 is not between N2 and O2, then it moves on to if I3 is between N3 and O3 etc. Thats why I was using two integers, i and j, to hold the value in column I constant while checking against every value in columns N and O.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, for each row you want to check if the value in column I is between at least one pair of values in columns N and O? That is for I2 you want to see whether N2 < I2 < O2 or N3 < I2 < O3 or N4 < I2 < O4 etc. If yes then you paste the value in P2 to J2. Then you want to do the same for I3, I4, I5 etc.?

Comment: Hi, yes that is exactly it. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Edited above, is this what your looking for?

Comment: As regards this comment "'Once you've found one pair of N and O that satisfies the condition, you move on to the next row, by forcing the j loop to end." that's not the correct way use `Exit For` instead...

Comment: Thanks EEM, I'd forgotten what the wording in VBA was. Edited above.